# Get reference to uninitialized std::vector element

Tags: c++, performance, vector, stdvector

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void ProcessVect(std::vector<double>& myInVect)
{
    std::vector<double> myOutVect(myInVect.size());

    for (size_t i =0; i < myInVect.size(); i++)
    {
        ProcessValue(myInVect[i], myOutVect[i]); // ProcessValue(double in, double& out);
    }

    DoSomething(myOutVect);
}
```

This code works, but has the disadvantage that `myOutVect` is initialized with zeros first and than overwritten by the value calculated in `ProcessValue`.

I have to do this for large vectors and speed matters. The function `ProcessValue` cannot be changed to accept vectors.

**Now my question:**
Is there a way to pass a reference to an uninitialized vector element to a function?

I have tried `myOutVect.reserve()` without initializing `myOutVect`, but this gives me an "index out of bounds" error.

Other solutions to my problem are of course also welcome.

Comment: That zero-initialization does not affect your performance much.

Comment: [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) (and `reserve`)? But I doubt it really matters.

Comment: *I have to do this for large vectors and speed matters*  -- Have you really measured the performance?

Comment: I think you should really profile your code and make sure you're timing release, optimized builds.   Also, you're concerned about the vector, but why not the same concern for the `for` loop?  Why are you not using iterators instead of having to call `operator [ ]` each time in the loop?

Comment: @BoBTFish: in my experience, `push_back` with `std::vector` of primitive types is significantly worse than zero-initializing and then doing a straight vector access.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Unfortunately I don't have a good profiler available at the moment. I did measure the duration of reserving and initializing an 8000 size vector of double using boost cpu_timer. The result is that reserving takes 19µs and initializing 40µs.

In comparison, the total computation time of my code is ~400µs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I used the following code for measuring (hope I did it correct:)):

`int i = 1;
boost::timer::cpu_timer t;
for(;i<1000;i++)
{
    std::vector<double> a(8000);
}
boost::timer::nanosecond_type t1(t.elapsed().wall);


i=1;
boost::timer::cpu_timer tt;
for(;i<1000;i++)
{
    std::vector<double> b;
    b.reserve(8000);
}
boost::timer::nanosecond_type t2(tt.elapsed().wall);`

Comment: Use a raw array guarded by `unique_ptr`.

Comment: keep your vector as a member of your class and reinitialize it's values with zero, do not reallocate it. This is the fastest way you can use it. Or even if you don't care what values does it contain, why would you even reinitialize it? Just override its values!

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector::reserve` does seem like a good way of doing that.

You probably got your exception because `reserve` only allocates memory, it doesn't change the length. Therefore you still have to call `push_back` or `emplace_back`.

Try this:

```
void ProcessVect(std::vector<double>& myInVect)
{
    std::vector<double> myOutVect;
    myOutVect.reserve(myInVect.size());

    for (size_t i =0; i < myInVect.size(); i++)
    {
        double v;
        ProcessValue(myInVect[i], v); // ProcessValue(double in, double& out);
        myOutVect.push_back(v);
    }

    DoSomething(myOutVect);
}
```

**EDIT**: As Matteo pointed out in the comments, this solution may be worse than zero-initialization. A quick check of mine on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-O9',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4BuCIBcD2AnAPgChRJZFUBnLORAMwDoALYtHEOJABTxwgUqUAagENYCABQQcYakjg4YAIygIAZABp5ileoCUAbiJsOSACI4AyjgC2CLE3ABzKTLnU4ALk8Zs%2BFArKqgRqIoZExuycPHwCwphYEh7evrh4ATrBakg2AJ4AkmBCCXpEAN5ESFVIyT4J/oG6BDm5APIwWMXYRtUt7Z0JDHgCCHgYEnmFXVgMlCAAXpJ64ZXVdPhISQsIAPpYSCBIALwADAYHqC1Tg3OLEoYHANSPpb0Vvb2NqkhoPR9VMX4glE4gmBSKCQA2iAALpaNAPAD0iO4vCBwjEMEkX2Q4C0OOyiiw4X%2BVTy/WmDAADjBKEwdkoRBAANYSBF/KoAXwivQs1jsDmcYIpJSMnKAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) shows that it is compiler-dependant, some always check the capacity, some optimize it out. On the whole, I can only recommend to run your profiler and see what's faster under your circumstances!

Comment: For vectors of primitive types `push_back` is generally worse than zero initializing - zero initialization can be performed in a really fast pass, and then storing elements amounts to a pointer dereference; OTOH, `push_back` requires checking the vector capacity every time, incrementing it and adjusting the logical size. In tight loops this is often really bad (the waste in registers, memory accesses, instruction cache and branches can be significant).

Answer (score 0):

One useful trick is to just avoid recreating (and rezeroing) the result vector by passing it in as an argument:

```
void ProcessVect(std::vector<double>& myInVect, std::vector<double>& myOutVect)
{
    assert(myInVect.size()==myOutVect.size());
    for (size_t i =0; i < myInVect.size(); i++)
    {
        ProcessValue(myInVect[i], myOutVect[i]); // ProcessValue(double in, double& out);
    }
    DoSomething(myOutVect);
}
```

The caller can then reuse the same output vector across repeated calls.

If you're in a class you can make the `myOutVect` a class member instead, but beware that it makes `ProcessVect` less thread safe.

You could also handle the case where the length of the input vector changes, by resizing the output vector to match, which should only reallocate if the new size is larger.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe create static vector, so the data would be readen from exe file to memory once. static vector myOutVect(100000);
for example: 
    `static vector a(10000);
    static_cast<vector<int>>(a);
    auto itr =a.begin();
    *itr=10;`

Comment: it's just an alternative

Comment: What if there are 100,001 elements?